# PHP: proceed to link after a jQueryUI dialog box appears

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a PHP method that actually displays a list of currently logged in users. 
It puts all active users into a table like this:

```
echo '<td><a href="drop.php?uid=' . $id . '" class="DropUser" id="">' . $uname . '</td>';
```

So, you may see that there is a link also to be able to log out current user.

I want to create a jQueryUI dialog box that appears `.on('click')` of that link. But I am not able to generate the same link in Javascript to redirect.

Is it possible to create a dialog box that acts like an `alert()` (stops executing before the "Ok" button is clicked)? Or is there any other solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wouldn't like to use AJAX:

```
$('.DropUser').click( function () {
// use alert
alert('Alerttext');
// and jump to your target
location.pathname='drop.php?uid=' + $(this).attr('id');
});
```

and your php/html:

```
echo '<td><a href="#" class="DropUser" id="'. $id . '">' . $uname . '</td>';
```

UPDATE: (this) refers to the current link...

Comment: The problem is that `alert()` has only one button and the script will continue executing anyway, regardless of what had been clicked - an OK button or the "Close window" button.

Comment: Using AJAX is quite different and I can not imagine what to do with an AJAX. I will have to rewrite the whole PHP method that handles it. I am not familiar with AJAX, actually :(